# num_reads count of zram is not changing in sync with number of read issued from zram node while using dd command?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, dd

I am using the `dd` command to perform read from `/dev/block/zram0` as follows:

```
dd if=/dev/block/zram0 of=/dev/null bs=4096 count=10 sync`
```

Ideally on executing the above command, `cat /sys/block/zram0/num_reads` should show the value `x+10` assume `x` was initial value before issuing the command. But, its not. It is  showing `x` again.

However, After executing the command I received following message:

```
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
40960 bytes (40kB) copied, xxxx s, ss.s kB/s
```

After freeing the caches `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` I received the similar message as above of successful write/read on executing the very same command. But then I see that `cat /sys/block/zram0/num_reads` shows value `x+y` not `x+10`.

can someone explain why so ?

Comment: Possibly block-layer read-ahead or read-combining... Is "y" less than 10, or greater?

Comment: @twalberg its greater than 10. Actually it depends on `count` and `bs` values. may I asked why you asked  y value  ?

Comment: Because if you did 10 reads from user-land, but the read counter in the driver incremented by less than 10, it would indicate that reads were somehow combined (or some reads fail to get counted), whereas if it increments by more than 10, it may indicate reads being split, or other sources of read activity...

Comment: Just forget to mention in question that `failed_reads` are zero. 
Read might got split ? Since we are simply reading from zram node why ?